# Change the path of localdb with EF Code First

Tags: ef-code-first, clickonce, localdb

i'm changing the setup of an application to a clickonce application.

I'm using SQL Server Express and the EntityFramework with the code first approach.

The MDF of the database is stored at %USERPROFILE%/database.mdf. Now i have to change the location to the %USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Apps/ …

I tried to use this Connection string

```
connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=MIADbContext;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\database.mdf"
```

But with this connectionstring i get an error:

```
 System.ArgumentException: Expansion of |DataDirectory| failed while processing the connection string. Ensure that |DataDirectory| is set to a valid fully-qualified path.
```

I don't know why this doesn't work. any ideas to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the path of the localDB in 3 steps

1. Detach the database
2. Copy and paste the localdb database to a different location
3. Attach the database with the new location

Query to detach DB

```
EXEC sp_detach_db 'aspnet-IdentityApplication-E2BBF1E6-123-4567-8910-07BC0413419B', 'true';
```

Query to attach DB

```
CREATE DATABASE [aspnet-IdentityApplication-E2BBF1E6-123-4567-8910-07BC0413419B]  
    ON (FILENAME = 'D:\Test\aspnet-IdentityApplication-E2BBF1E6-123-4567-8910-07BC0413419B.mdf'),   
    (FILENAME = 'D:\Test\aspnet-IdentityApplication-E2BBF1E6-123-4567-8910-07BC0413419B_log.ldf')   
    FOR ATTACH;
```